# Using bootstrap toggle in PHP

Tags: php, node.js, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use the plugin "bootstrap toggle" which can be found on that address:
http://www.bootstraptoggle.com

I am developing my website on php + html using apache on debian OS and the installation instruction of the plugin are very unclear to me.

It says to use the bower install to install the plugin, but then to install bower from their website I should have npm, but when checking out on what is npm it's a node.js stuff, and I want to use it on php.

Please help if you can. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bower install is just if you want to use Bower to install it. If not, just download the package or refer to their CDNs as they do at the very top:

```
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.0/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.0/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
```

Since you don't know what Bower is you can definitely safely ignore that part. :)

Answer (score 1):

ignore this part if you don't use Bower (= tool to manage easily frameworks, libraries.. )
You just need to put this following into your  :

```
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.0/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.0/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
```

You could also download these packages (to make your app run faster).